# Use SparkLauncher to programmatically submit a spark job to the dse spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I am relatively new to Spark and DSE and I am trying to submit a spark job to the DSE spark cluster programmatically?

I am using the org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher api. I tried following the documentation for the SparkLauncher.

```
Process launcher = new SparkLauncher().setAppName("appName")
                    .setAppResource("spark-job.jar")
                    .setSparkHome("spark-home")
                    .setMainClass("main-class")
                    .setVerbose(true).launch();
launcher.waitFor();
```

But it doesn't seem to launch the job on the dse cluster. I can trigger the job manually using: **dse spark-submit command**

Will appreciate any help here. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has something to do with not setting your sparkHOme. Identify your spark home In DSE and then add

```
.setSparkHome("sparkHomeDir")
```

And You rather use SparkHandle than blocking wait.

```
SparkAppHandle handle = launcher.startApplication();
```